# How to handle a highly unbalanced dataset

Tags: security, machine-learning, deep-learning

I was checking the [dataset CERT V4.1](https://www.cert.org/insider-threat/tools/index.cfm) which was synthesized to simulate insider threats. I realized that it contains about 850K samples and there are about 200 samples considered as malicious data. Is this normal? am I missing something here? If this is the case, how can I handle such data if I want to use deep learning?

Answer (score 1):

If you have unbalanced Data you have many options (see link below).
Additional to these there is a really interesting approach that works like this:

> 1: you randomly split your 850K negative samples in blocks of 200
>
> 2: you build one classifier for every block where you put all positive samples in together with one block of the negative samples
>
> 3: Use all classifiers in paralell and let them vote, find a good threshold of how many positive votes you need to be "sure enough" to classify the test sample as positive

Regarding that your data is 200 vs 850K (meaning around 4250 Classifiers) you might consider to combine this approach with one of the others, like duplicating mentioned by @Prune or one of the approaches explained in the link below.

Here you have some approaches dealing with imbalanced data
http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is normal in many paradigms: a large majority of the traffic is "normal".  You handle this simply by being careful to distribute the negative samples proportionately in your train, test, and validation sets.  For instance, if your desired proportions are 50-30-20, make sure that you have about 100 malicious samples in the training set, 60 in testing, and 20 in validation.

If the training fails in this paradigm, you can also try adding multiple instances of each malicious sample to each of the sets: duplicate those 100 records several times; for instance, add 10 copies of each sample to each of the data sets (but still do *not* cross from one set to another -- you would now have 1000 malicious samples in the training set, not 10 copies each of the original 200).

Comment: What do you mean by "do not cross from one set to another"? Also, do you think that deep learning can come up with a good model in such data?

Comment: I mean that each observation appears in only one of the three data sets, although it may appear multiple times.

Comment: Can "deep learning" find a "good" model?  That's such a wide range that the answer *has* to be "yes".  However, it depends on whether your data coverage is broad and separable enough to support your personal definition of "good", and what methods in the wide world of "deep learning" you apply.